# Remove application insights

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-application-insights

I notice that in my asp.net core web application, in the network activity I see a `ai.0.js` file being blocked (presumably by my ad blocker). I googled and found it has to do with Application Insights. I don't recall adding that to my project, and I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of it.

There doesn't appear to by any trace of it in my actual solution, and I've even disabled it in the Tools/Options/etc. area but that doesn't affect any of the source code that actually gets updated so I know that's not going to stop it from serving up that js file in production.

So how can I prevent it from trying to serve this js file in production?

Comment: Can you add more info? what kind of application are you building? what .net framework (core or 4.x) and where do you host it (Azure can add this on top of your app). Also - have you tried following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/remove-application-insights?tabs=net ? seems to answer your direct question

Comment: @TGN12 Sorry, I forgot to finish tagging. I have added core and azure.You mention Azure can add this on top of my app; can I get rid of it?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the steps in the MS link I've provided?

Comment: @TGN12 Yes. I'm thinking this is something Azure must do that can't be stopped.

Comment: I don't think there's anything that can't be stopped.
Can you share your Layout.cshtml file content?

Comment: @BVernon Any luck here? Looking the contents of Layout.cshtml would help, as TGN12 suggested. Please include it in the question if you can.